# OOBE not run after sysprep, only a login screen is displayed

Tags: windows-10, sysprep

I try to prepare a Windows 10 21H1 installation with sysprep for imaging. I activated OOBE and generalize. Sysprep says that it was successful, but it ran to quick and the log file (`setupact.log`) ends abrubtly, see below.

The problem is that after a reboot I'm not presented with the OOBE first run setup stuff but just with the login screen for "other user" and I can't login there.

The panther directory has an empty `setuperr.log` and `setupact.log` contains two warnings, no errors and a lot of entries like this at the end:

```
...
2021-08-12 10:07:51, Warning                      TapiSysPrep.dll:RetainTapiLocations:RegQueryValueEx() returned 2
...
2021-08-12 10:08:15, Warning               SYSPRP SPPNP: Failed to configure oem31.inf (fn.inf). Err = 0x430
...
2021-08-12 10:08:19, Info                  SYSPRP SPPNP: Configured oem53.inf (wiman.inf).
2021-08-12 10:08:19, Info                  SYSPRP SPPNP: Configured oem54.inf (qmuxmdm.inf).
```

Comment: Have you tried to dump your driver store and figure out which driver is in oem31.inf (fn.inf) and then uninstall that driver before sysprep?

Comment: @NiKiZe Thank you for your tip, that seems to work. The file `fn.inf` belongs to `Lenovo Fn and function keys` or just `Fn and function keys`. I wouldn't have expected that this warning and in particular this driver is the cause. Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the warning is about a driver, investigate the driver store with `dism /Online /Get-Drivers`

Search for `oem31.inf` and/or `fn.inf` and try to uninstall that device before sysprep.

If confirmed it is the driver that is the culprit, the fun with trying to understand why starts. (But maybe that is a non issue if the driver just reinstalls after first login)